# Perl, split a string before the first alphabetic character

Tags: string, perl, substr

In Perl, I'm looking to split a string before the first letter (regardless of its position).  I don't want the delimiter to disappear.

For example, if the string was `12345AB2345` I want to split on the first letter `A` I want two strings:  `12345` and `AB2345`.

I tried using code like the following, but it does it does not split correctly.

```
$string = "12345A2345"
$substring = substr($string, 0, index($string, /[a-zA-Z]/);
$remainder = substr($string, index($string, /[a-zA-Z]/);
```

There can be more than one letter in the string.

I think my problem deals with the fact that substr cannot use regular expressions.

Comment: Do the strings contain only ASCII letters and digits?

Comment: Yes. I don't think that I need anything other than numbers and English letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use `split` here, since that's what you're doing after all. Below I give you the choice between 3 ways:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

while( <DATA>)
  { chomp;
    my( $string, $expected_substring, $expected_remainder)= split /\s+/;

    { # method 1: split on letter, captured letter is added to the remainder
      #           the 3rd arg to split is the LIMIT (see perldoc -f split)
      my( $substring, $letter, $remainder)= split /([a-zA-Z])/, $string, 2;
      $remainder= $letter . $remainder if $letter;

      is( $substring, $expected_substring, "method 1, substring, s: '$string'");
      is( $remainder, $expected_remainder, "method 1, remainder, s: '$string'");
    }

    { # method 2: add space before letter, split on space 
      my $string_copy= $string;          # or $string would be modified
      $string_copy=~ s/([a-zA-Z])/ $1/;
      my( $substring, $remainder)= split / /, $string_copy, 2;

      is( $substring, $expected_substring, "method 2, substring, s: '$string'");
      is( $remainder, $expected_remainder, "method 2, remainder, s: '$string'");
    }

    { # method 3: method 2 shortened using s//r (perl 5.14 and above)
      my( $substring, $remainder)= split / /,  $string=~ s/([a-zA-Z])/ $1/r, 2;

      is( $substring, $expected_substring, "method 3, substring, s: '$string'");
      is( $remainder, $expected_remainder, "method 3, remainder, s: '$string'");
    }
  }

done_testing();

# test data, string, substring and remainder are on one line, space separated
__DATA__
12345A678  12345 A678  
12345AB678 12345 AB678
12345A67B8 12345 A67B8
12345678   12345678
```

Answer (score 3):

And yet another way:

```
my $string = "12345A2345";
my ($substring, $remainder) = split /(?=[a-z])/i, $string, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
my ($substring,$remainder) = $string =~ /^([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z].*)$/ ;
```

If you need to handle the case where there are no letters, then you could do:

```
my ($substring,$remainder) = $string =~ /^([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z].*)?$/ ;
```

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. I have edited the question to better explain myself. I think that code will work only if there is one letter in the string??? (That is everything from the second letter on will be lost?)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` matches one letter.  then `.*` matches the rest of the line.

Comment: This is good, but if there are no letters at all in the string then this pattern will fail to match anything. Something like this might be closer: `my ($substring, $remainder) = $string =~ /^([^[:alpha:]]*)(.*)$/;`

Comment: The question asked to match 'the first letter'.  You can make the second () conditional if you need to allow for no letters.

Comment: @J.A. What is supposed to happen if there is more than one letter in the string? Should it be split on those letters as well?

Comment: @qwrrty look at the example at the top, all the letters go in the second half.